# jsoup to get a particular element in Tablw

Tags: java, css, jsoup

I have html page that extract the information from:

```
table class="students">
<tbody>
<tr class="rz" style="color:red;" onclick="location.href='//andy.pvt.com';">
<td>
<a title="Display Andy website,Andy" href="//andy.pvt.com">15</a>
</td>
<td>Andy jr</td>
<td align="right">44.31</td>
<td align="right">23.79</td>
<td align="right">57</td>
<td align="right">1,164,700</td>
<td align="right">0.12</td>
<td align="center">
<td align="left">0.99</td>
<td align="right">
</tr>
```

=
I want to get Andy, 15 andy.pvt.lom.

I am able to extract this table using doc.select(table).get

I am not able to extract the information I am looking.

how to get the "tables.select("xxxx");"
can you please help me with the xxx what I am missing?

Comment: What have you tried and what does it return? Certainly you should be able to figure out how to get an href attribute, right? And getting 15 is as simple as getting the `text()` from an `a` tag.

Comment: I tried ; tables = doc.select("table").get(0); than tables.select("a title). In the tables I am trying to get what is there in a title which in this case is "Display Andy website,Andy". But did not see any thing getting selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> I tried ; tables = doc.select("table").get(0); than tables.select("a title).

You want something more along the lines of

```
tables.select("a[href]").attr("href"); // to get your String
```

and

```
tables.select("a[href]").text(); // to get your number
```

e.g.,

```
  Elements tables = doc.select("table");
  String hrefAttr = tables.select("a[href]").attr("href");
  System.out.println("href attribute: " + hrefAttr);
  String number = tables.select("a[href]").text();
  System.out.println("number: " + number);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not getting the url printed with a[href]? and how to get the name selected . I can see 15 getting printed with ("a").text

Comment: @TheLearner: Please see edit. The tutorial is pretty self explanatory. You'll want to dig into it more.